# How does ghost get real IP from nginx(reverse proxy)?

Tags: nginx, ghost

I have configured nginx as a reverse proxy. However, ghost always gets the same ip 127.0.0.1 from request forwarded to it by nginx.

How can I make ghost to get the real IP from nginx?

My configuration of nginx includes the following statements

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;    
proxy_set_header  X-real-ip $remote_addr;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try retrieve the IP address first from headers:

```
var ip = req.headers['x-real-ip'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

It is not recommended to override `req.connection.remoteAddress` directly since it will confuse other programmers you collaborated with. But it is technically possible. The `remoteAddress` is a getter so you can't assign value to it directly, you need to [define your own getter](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3323#issuecomment-5942779):

```
req.connection.__defineGetter__('remoteAddress', function() {
    return req.headers['x-real-ip'];
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I want to modify the source code of ghost to let it use real IP in all place. Can I directly sign req.connection.remoteAddress with the value of req.headers['x-real-ip'] in the place where request object is first generated? In this way, req.connection.remoteAddress has the value of real IP and I have to change only one place in the source code. :)